# Click on image in listview should be open in another activity with path

Tags: android

I am passing URL of images from showing the image the image in another activity when i click on image.Clickable image should be open in another activity. please help me how can i do this. I am pasting few line of code which i have done yet.

```
            ItemHolder holder = itemHolder;
                holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String urlstring="This is my service to get the images from server";
                        String imagestring= messageBean.getImagePath().toString();
                        imagestring = imagestring.replace("./","/");
                        urlstring = urlstring+imagestring;
                        // messageBean.getTotalVotes()
                        ((Message) activity).SendImageUrl(urlstring);}
                });
```

from this path i want to open the image in another activity on click it.

Comment: So call startService to start the other activity and pass it the thing to display.

Comment: can you you give me code

Answer (score 0):

Set tag to each Imageview in your adapter.

Ex:

```
    ItemHolder holder = itemHolder;
    holder.imageView.setTage("your url");

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String imagestring= holder.imageView.getTag().toString();
                            imagestring = imagestring.replace("./","/");
                            urlstring = urlstring+imagestring;
                            // messageBean.getTotalVotes()
Intent mIntent = new Intent(yourActivityName.this, classToBelaunched.class);
mIntent.putStringExtra("url",urlString);
startActivity(mIntent);

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.setOnClickListener(...){
   ... onClick(){
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url", "place your url here");
stratActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

In second Activity write this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `messageBean` is, but what you can do is pass that bean into the new activity via the intent's bundle.  As so:

```
ItemHolder holder = itemHolder;
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("messageBean", messageBean);
        myIntent.startActivity();
    });
```

And then in the activity that you opened:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    String urlstring="This is my service to get the images from server";
    MessageBean messageBean = (MessageBean)bundle.get("messageBean");
    String imagestring= messageBean.getImagePath().toString();
    imagestring = imagestring.replace("./","/");
    urlstring = urlstring+imagestring;
    // messageBean.getTotalVotes()
    SendImageUrl(urlString);
}
```